# Finding items which are similar

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, knn, apache-spark-ml

I have a big database of many items of retail company. If I would like to find the items which are similar to any particular item, can I use pearson correlation in Spark ML to do that? Is there any other better algorithm to do it? How do I make sure the machine also learns as it evolves?

Edit - I implemented Mapreduce program to find distance between various features. But how can I make it as Machine learning solution? Suppose if I let the program identify the correct neighbor, how can the program make use of this learning for next time?

Comment: Why is there a down vote? Is there any problem with the question?

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure ML recommendation model it is easy to perform tasks such as "reltaed purchase items" it would be a quick and easy start.

https://gallery.cortanaintelligence.com/MachineLearningAPI/Recommendations-2

Comment: This has some examples around relating a customer to purchased item or item similarities based on purchases. My requirement is little different. How do I relate item to another item in the catalog of website using attributes of both items?